# Client-side hide/show functionality

Tags: mysql, html, perl

I have a link on HTML page which calls the perl script. Perl script will fetch the data from mysql database and display on HTML page.

```
<a href = cgi-bin/customers.pl> show all customers </a>
```

There are some filters in HTML page.

Only chennai customers -- while endusers clicks on this, only chennai customers should display

Only mumbai customers -- while endusers clicks on this, only mumbai customers should display

Do I need to run a separate mysql query for all these customers, or I can hide / again show them on client side??

Answer (score 0):

the question is to query all data and send to client or to query just the necessary and sent to client.

the answer depends on your data size. if your data set is small, i suggest to query all at once and hide and show at client.

if your data set is large, then just query the needed ones.

besides the current data set size, think about the growth rate. how fast and how big does your data grow. all those will change how you implement it.

Comment: Another thing to consider: the solution where everything loads at once is suitable for applying **progressive enhancement** techniques and therefore can easily be made **accessible** to user agents without JavaScript support, whereas the loading as needed scheme cannot.